# Docusaurus: i18n and relative link build errors

Tags: markdown, documentation, docusaurus

Ahoy! Looking for some general guidance here.

We have a doc site that has both:

- A fair amount markdown files and
- Relative links to other markdown pages.

Maintaining relative links is a struggle with docs in different languages (markdown files in `i18n`); Build errors occur if we try to build the docs (i.e. `yarn build`) if there are relative links in our default doc page and not in the equivalent page in `i18n` directory.

For example, suppose I add this relative link `[](../directory/cat.md)`, in a markdown file called `file.md` in `docusaurus/docs/guides/directory/file.md`.

The doc build breaks if I don't update that same link (for the equivalent page) in my `i18n` folder (`docusaurus/i18n/*/docs/guides/directory/file.md`).

To resolve the build error, we need to update relative link in `docusaurus/i18n/*/docs/guides/directory/file.md`.

Any advice on how to reduce redundancy? (not updating ea. page each time we update a link in our default doc folder)?

We are considering switching to multi-domain or a hybrid deployment type...